# Delete data table with left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not understand MySQL delete when I need to delete data in a table with data from another table that depend on it.

For example if I want to delete a data in table 'factory', all data at table 'room' that depends on data at table 'factory is also deleted'.

Fac_ID is the primary key in 'factory' and foreign key in 'room'

below is my SQL code.

```
DELETE * FROM factory 
LEFT JOIN room ON room.Fac_ID = factory.Fac_ID 
WHERE factory.Fac_ID = :Fac_ID
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Why are you even doing a `LEFT JOIN` to `room` table ? It does not serve any purpose in your current query. `LEFT JOIN` will ensure that all the rows of the table `factory` are fetched, whether there is any matching row in the `room` table or not.

Comment: your query seems fine, what is the issue in it. check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d47d48/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a separate delete for this.

First is to delete foreign data

```
delete from room where Fac_ID = :Fac_ID
```

Then delete primary data

```
delete from factory where Fac_ID = :Fac_ID
```

Unless your table design is [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) (supported only in INNODB), you only need to delete the primary data

Comment: can i know how to combine it?

Comment: create a procedure to do this. Or you need to have a separate call on your UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your query because of which I think you are facing problem.

As per my understanding you have some records in Main table and some records in refrenced table. There are some case for which main table has some `id` but there is not entry in refrence table for that `id`. And for handling that case you applied `left join`.

But in your query you wrote reference table on left so basically it is taking all of the record from reference table which is kind of `inner join` in this case.

So for correcting this you need to interchange the key id pass in your query or you may use `right join` to select all records from main table.

```
DELETE * FROM factory 
LEFT JOIN room ON factory.Fac_ID = room.Fac_ID    --- here you applied left join   
WHERE factory.Fac_ID = :Fac_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows you to delete rows from multiple tables at the same time.  The syntax is:

```
DELETE f, r
    FROM factory f LEFT JOIN
         room r
         ON r.Fac_ID = f.Fac_ID 
    WHERE f.Fac_ID = :Fac_ID;
```

However, this is better set up as a cascading delete foreign key relationship between the two tables.